# Extracting files to current directory

Tags: bash, shell, find, tar

I want to find and tar/archive all my scripts ending .sh so I wrote something like that:

```
touch ~/archive.tar; find ~ -type f -name '*.sh' -exec rvf ~/archive.tar {} \;
```

The problem is that after I make an archive called archive.tar the archive won't unpack the files into current directory but to directories where it was archived from. For example, there can be archived script called `~/Desktop/wtf/delete.sh` but it will be extracted into folder `wtf` not into current directory where I currently am. So how do I edit my find script to have all scripts in this format ./filename.sh?

Comment: Use `cd; find .` rather than `find ~`.  Then the paths in the tarball will be `./path/to/script.sh` rather than `/home/username/path/to/script.sh`.  You can also use the `-C` option for `tar` to specify the base path to extract tarballs into.

Comment: @DopeGhoti But if you cd somewhere there can be another direcory and also he probably does not know where all his .sh scripts are located.

Comment: In the OP, he's explicitly `find`ing from the home directory.  `cd` with no parameters goes to that location.

Comment: with GNU `find`, you can use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, and `find` will cd to each matching file's directory before running the command.   See `man tar` and search for `-execdir` for details.  BTW, use `+` to terminate the `-exec` or `execdir` rather than `\;`...that will run `tar` with as many filenames as possible, rather than running `tar` once for **each** filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `GNU tar`, you can say:

```
tar --transform 's/.*\///' -xzf archive.tgz
```

This will strip everything up to the last slash from the file names.